# book example not working in SWIFT Playground

Tags: swift

I'm looking for an explanation on playground behavior for **Swift**. On page 76 of the book **Beginning Swift Programming** the doSomething function doesn't behave in **Xcode** as described.

```
func doSomething(num1: Int, num2: Int) {
   println(num1, num2)
}

doSomething(5,6)
```

The book doesn't show an answer, but I expect a response like `(5,6)`. However, I get no error nor any response. Change the action to `println(num1)` and `doSomething(5,6)` works. It produces `5`. So does `doSomething(5)`. For that matter. Change it to `println((num1, num2))` and `doSomething(5,6)` yields `(5,6)`.

I'm using Xcode v.6.4 on a Mac running Yosemite. What's going on?

Comment: see [this](http://swiftstub.com/233833927/?v=gm)

Comment: I am getting (5,6) as a response.What exact info do you want?

Comment: Not surprising, since sometimes Playground seems to need an extra CR or Space. In this case I've typed in exactly what the book shows, however, and get nothing. In fact I copy/pasted in the code. Someone showed a problem with doing that from MSWord. In this case the source is Acrobat.

Comment: Can you link the book and also tel us what chapter. Or section. Page numbers are useless in ebooks.

Comment: The book is "Beginning Swift Programming" by Wei-Meng Lee. https://www.overdrive.com/media/2056217/beginning-swift-programming The example is on the second page of Section 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the `println()` function takes only one parameter.

You either do:

```
println((num1, num2)) // for printing as a Tuple object
```

or:

```
println("\(num1), \(num2)") // for printing as a String object
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

---

When in a **normal project** rather than **Playground**, the code you provided actually works. However, you will have to call `doSomething(5, num2: 6)` instead. (Swift 1.2/2.0)

Comment: Authoritative reference, but the book author doesn't seem worried about that.  :)  Nor does Rohit.

Comment: I edited my answer. The code does work in a normal project, with different call. The book could have been referencing Swift 1.0, while Xcode 6.4 use 1.2.

Comment: The book text may be behind some Swift changes. E.g., I noticed "countElements( )" changed to "count( )". Your comment also seems to indicate that you tried it in Playground. So thanks for the extra effort.

Comment: FWIW I tried your suggestion on explicit use of the variable name num2. Playground said: "Extraneous argument label 'num2:' in call. Several folks have suggested other ways to get the expected result, so that's less my issue than figuring out quirks in Playground, so your inputs are especially helpful.

Comment: afaik, Apple changed so many things and broke my project so many times that I almost pissed off and gave up using Swift. It's a new language and still evolving. The book is really nice indeed, but after all, it's always better to try out yourself and read the Xcode release note from time to time. BTW, Swift 2 has some major syntax too, like the rename println() back to print(). So you never know. :)

Comment: This thread shows what I think is best about stackoverflow. Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 0):

It's **Swift** basic knowledge and suggest you to look up answer rather than ask here. If you want to print something using `println` with variable. You have to use `\(variableName)`. For example:

`println("\(num1), \(num2)")`

Comment: I agree this works. My question had to do with why something in an ebook doesn't seem to work. One might argue that reading a basic book on Swift in fact constitutes looking up the answer.